# C# - problem with very small numbers - not enough digits in double datatype

Tags: c#, double, precision

I'm writing a program in C# which suppose to calculate very small numbers. However, all my calculations are getting NaN value because they are too small for the 'double' datatype.

Is there an option in C# to deal with such situations?

Thanks,
Eden.

Comment: What is a "very small" number? Any example of what you're doing?

Comment: Define "very small numbers". And please give an example of a calculation that results in NaN.

Comment: How can you get NaN just with very small (eps-like) values? I can only think of 1.0/x where x is very small. But that would result in +infinity. It must be a NaN introduced at some point.

Comment: Hi

very quick answers. thanks.

I calculate binomial p-values with with very big (apparently) numbers. 
For example, binomial-coefficient(5200,2500)*p^(2600)*(1-p)^(2700) (and making sum of these)

I tried using logs and than using exp..
I don't receive "NaN" - my mistake, because I used Power instead exponent.
Nevertheless, I still can't make my calculations for the above numbers.

I can't use decimal because all the Math functions use double. Unless I forget something

Answer (score 2):

try [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

Edit:
Also, .NET 4 introduces [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28VS.100%29.aspx) which could probably be used to represent whatever floating point values\data range you are trying to represent.

Comment: Being a big "integer" I don't think it is going to be able to store floating point values. You would have to use one BigInteger as a coefficient, and a second as a exponent in a form of scientific notation.

Comment: Or you use fixed point arithmetic with an excessive precision of some 500 decimal digits.

Comment: SealedSun explained what I failed to explain when I suggested BigInteger, thanks.

Comment: can't use decimal. The Math.pow, and all that use double.